# Make jquery autocomplete common

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC - C# app with jquery autocomplete feature for some text boxes. Each View has autocomplete code, some are for the same field (different views), and some different fields as well.

ex.

- `Invoice\Create` View `customer` text box
- `Payment\Create` View `customer` text box
- `Payment\Create` View `Invoice Number` text box

having autocomplete feature. All working as expected.

Here is a sample code (which is in each view for each control - this is for Customer)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#CustomerName").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetCustomers", "Invoices")',
                datatype: "json",
                data: {
                    term: request.term
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (val, item) {
                        return {
                            label: val.CustomerName,
                            value: val.CustomerName,
                            CustomerId: val.CustomerId
                        }
                    }))
                }
            })
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#CustomerId").val(ui.item.CustomerId);
        }
    });
});
```

Now what I want is, create a common function in a file in Scripts Folder  and call that, along with parameters, whenever I need this autocomplete feature to any control in any view.Is there a way to achieve it?

I tried the `$(document).ready` function in the view's script section, and few other options, but was unsuccessful.

**Please let me know, at least whether this could be done or not**

Answer (score 0):

```
function (elementId,controllerName,actionName,fieldName) {
    $("#"+elementId+"").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'api/'+controllerName+'/'+actionName+'',
                datatype: "json",
                data: {
                    term: request.term
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (val, item) {
                        return {
                            label: val[0],
                            value: val[1],
                            fieldName: val.fieldId
                        }
                    }))
                }
            })
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#"+elementId+"").val(ui.item.fieldName);
        }
    });
}
```