# Edit - Save while in Index View without going to Edit View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have an MVC - C# app. It has few pages with `Create`, `Edit`, `Delete` features generated by scafolding wizards. All working good. I need to do a different operation, which cannot be autogenerated.

That is

1. I have a data model with Entity Framework and a View Model for this
2. All necessary data for the index are available and getting displayed, as a html table
3. I changed 1 column of the table to `@EditorFor`, so that I can make changes to the values.

What I want is a way to pass the contents of the view to the controller, along with the *data I changed* in the **editable control**. What **I don't want** is to **go to a different Edit View** and do it there.

I tried the following:

- Put the `@using (Html.BeginForm())` and make the save button a submit button
- Pass the model values with the action link button as in the following and get the changes in `Edit method` in the controller

  ```
            <a href="@Url.Action("Edit","InvoicePayments",
                    new {
                        PaymentId = item.PaymentId,
                        InvoiceId = item.InvoiceId,
  ```

Please let me know what i need to do in order to make this work.

Comment: I don't know, why my questions are not answered !! :(

At least give me a hint or any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

model

```
public class SampleViewModel
{
    public SampleViewModel()
    {
        
    }
    public SampleViewModel(string f1, string f2, string f3 )
    {
        this.FieldOne = f1;
        this.FieldTwo = f2;
        this.FieldThree = f3;
    }
    public string FieldOne { get; set; }
    public string FieldTwo { get; set; }
    public string FieldThree { get;set; }
}
public class MasterViewModel
{
    public MasterViewModel()
    {
        this.svmLst = new List<SampleViewModel>();

        SampleViewModel svm1 = new SampleViewModel("a", "b", "c");
        SampleViewModel svm2 = new SampleViewModel("p", "", "r");
        SampleViewModel svm3 = new SampleViewModel("z", "y", "z");

        svmLst.Add(svm1);
        svmLst.Add(svm2);
        svmLst.Add(svm3);
    }
    public List<SampleViewModel> svmLst { get; set; }
}
```

controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
    

        return View(new HelloWorldMvcApp.MasterViewModel());
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HelloWorldMvcApp.MasterViewModel model)
    {   
        //your value is stored here and sent back to controller in model container
        //you can see the value you edited in return page FieldTwoColum
        
        
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

view

```
@model HelloWorldMvcApp.MasterViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- template from http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started -->

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

        <!-- CSS Includes -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
    
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.svmLst[0].FieldOne)
            </th>

            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.svmLst[0].FieldTwo)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.svmLst[0].FieldThree)
            </th>

            <th></th>
        </tr>
      
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
          for(int i=0;i<Model.svmLst.Count();i++)
          {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.svmLst[i].FieldOne)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.svmLst[i].FieldOne)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem =>  Model.svmLst[i].FieldTwo)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>  Model.svmLst[i].FieldThree)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem =>  Model.svmLst[i].FieldThree)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Edit"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        
    }
}
    </table>
    
            
    

        <!-- JS includes -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
        <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/4.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Deepani check it out if it is your answer please mark answer otherwise comment

Comment: I created a ViewModel for you and in that ViewModel you can iterate instances of smaller view model basically bigger view model has list of smaller view model and in your view you enumerate the list in big view model and when data is post backed you have all of data (big view model list) with modified value in it

Comment: i used for instead of foreach because foreach wont work and also using smapleviewmodel list wont work neither

Comment: Thanks @Alireza, that one worked. I need to make a bit of changes but this is more than enough.

Comment: would you mind give a shot to my other question. : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63438026/make-jquery-autocomplete-common

Answer (score 0):

https://dotnetfiddle.net/XDj2lW this is a .net fiddle

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace HelloWorldMvcApp
{
    
    public class SampleViewModel
    {
        public SampleViewModel()
        {
            this.FieldOne = "1";
            this.FieldTwo = "2";
            this.FieldThree = "3";
        }
        public string FieldOne { get; set; }
        public string FieldTwo { get; set; }
        public string FieldThree { get;set; }
    }
}
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace HelloWorldMvcApp
{
    
    public class SampleViewModel
    {
        public SampleViewModel()
        {
            this.FieldOne = "1";
            this.FieldTwo = "2";
            this.FieldThree = "3";
        }
        public string FieldOne { get; set; }
        public string FieldTwo { get; set; }
        public string FieldThree { get;set; }
    }
}

@model HelloWorldMvcApp.SampleViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- template from http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started -->

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

        <!-- CSS Includes -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            
    
                @using (Html.BeginForm())
                {
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FieldOne)
                        @Model.FieldOne
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FieldTwo)
                        @Model.FieldTwo
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FieldThree)
                        @Model.FieldThree
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FieldThree, new {@class="form-control"}) 
                    </div>
                
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success submit">Edit</button>
                }
    
                <br/><br/>
                <div class="alert alert-warning fade">
                    <img src="http://entechprod.blob.core.windows.net/dotnetfiddle/morpheus.jpg" style="max-width:100%;"/><br/><br/>
                    <strong><span class="alert-content"></span></strong>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- JS includes -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
        <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/4.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

content of net fiddle
basically you can use you strongly type model for index and pass the values to controller as one instance of that model with edited value

Comment: please mark answer cause god of coding is watching you :D or ask again in comment if you think this is wrong :( this is not wrong btw fiddle says so live long and prosper :P

Comment: @Deepani did you get your answer cause if you have you can click the tick button to mark it as answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But unfortunately it doesn't resolve the issue I raised. In my View, I have a a list of objects in a HTML table.  I need one of the columns in that to be editable (as similar to the  `@Html.TextBoxFor` in your code). Problem is that when I click the edit button, I do get the data passed to the Action Method in controller. 
If that can be done, I can save that record.

Comment: Its quite a bit lengthy. So I'll tell you what is different in the code you provided.
The model in View should be 
`@model IEnumerable<HelloWorldMvcApp.SampleViewModel>`

and the data is not as in an `Edit view`, instead, it is looped and filled as in an `Index view`. One of the field is EditorFor and I need the value user typed there to be passed to the controller.

Comment: I made changes to the same code that you gave me, so that you may find what I expect.
Please run the app, put a break point in [POST] Index and see whether the edited value is coming. It is not. and that is my issue.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/0eIYFE

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/80q2LG live long and prosper